# Set defaults for attrs subclass that uses validators from parent class?

Tags: python, python-attrs

Consider this minimal example:

```py
from attrs import define, field, validators

@define(kw_only=True)
class Vehicle:
    num_wheels: int = field(validator=validators.instance_of(int))

    @num_wheels.validator
    def validate_num_wheels(self, attribute, value) -> None:
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Number of wheels must be greater than 0")
```

How can I create subclasses of this parent class which set their own default values of `num_wheels` but still run the validators defined in the parent class? For example:

```py
@define
class Car(Vehicle):
    # num_wheels: int = 4  #! this doesn't work
    pass


@define
class Motorbike(Vehicle):
    # num_wheels: int = 2
    pass
```

I want to protect against `Car(num_wheels=3.14)` or `Car(num_wheels=-1)`. But also want `Car()` or `Motorbike()` to initialise with default values.

I've seen this answer which might be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67129088/11432894. It suggests this might be a solution?

```py
@define
class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, *, num_wheels: int = 4, **kwargs):
        self.__attrs_init__(num_wheels=num_wheels, **kwargs)
```

Comment: In some sense, it seems `num_wheels` should be a read-only property that is set by the class itself, not something the user can specify on a per-instant basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like at the core you would like to re-use field definitions which is unfortunately an open issue: https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/637

As mentioned in one of the comments, in this case the number of wheels should probably be part of the class – not an attribute. I guess you could also make your Vehicle class "abstract" and write [a validator](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#validators) that reads the attribute from the class (i.e. it would check `self.num_wheels` with `num_wheels` being a `ClassVar`).